# Loopback 2.4: how to query certain fields of related model via REST API

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, jugglingdb

I have User model over relational DB.

Each User can hasMany "users" where "chiefId" is FK.

```
"relations": {
    "users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "User",
      "foreignKey": "chiefId"
    },
}
```

I can query related users for each chief-user like this:

```
GET /users?filter={"include":"users"}
```

But it returns **full** user objects.

- How should I query only "name" properties of related users?
- Also is it possible to count related instances in one request to server?

Comment: not supported it seems, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903985/how-to-include-related-entities-in-rest-with-loopback-io

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A late reply but I just ran into this question now. It is possible:

```
filter: {
 include:{
  relation: "users",
  scope: {
   fields:["name"]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this part of the model?

Comment: @Bill Look at [include filter docs](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood this question is about adding a nested filter on an include level, which seems to be not yet supported: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/loopbackjs/T6onsYMJFOI/V4ILc3Obf3MJ

May be it's not the best way to approach this problem, but what you can do is a manual response transformation in .afterRemote('find', ...) hook.

Answer (score 0):

```
/users?filter[fields][0]=name
```

See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations-basic for more info.

Comment: This doesn't work for included objects.
And I need only "name" for **related** (or embedded) user objects!

Comment: do any of use cases in the example repo meet your use case? maybe this one /api/customers?filter[include][reviews]=author&filter[where][age]=21

Comment: I saw the use cases, but they don't limit fields returned from relation. As Alex Voitau said, this isn't supported yet.
Nevertheless thanks for response!